# Naming this chord?

Tags: theory, chords, harmony

The given image has a chord written (with the Treble clef above and the Bass clef under). The root of the chord is in the bass voice. 
May not have the 5th of the chord in this.

[image]

Please help me figure this out. Your help is appreciated!

Comment: Wait why is this off topic? It seems like a legit theory question. I can’t tell what that chord is. Cadd9Aug?

Comment: I see the reason for this being marked as off topic. But umm. On a real though how would one name this chord? I don’t see this is as identifying a chord from a song but more of a what convention applies here.

Comment: @xerotolerant exactly my thoughts, yeah it's off topic but also... that's an interesting chord; E G# C D G... damn  I'd probably look at it as a kind of altered dominant, E7alt but I guess that it'd be E+7(♯9) aka (Eaug7#9) if you wanted to be technical about it.  Cool chord for sure, I'd be curious to see what the context is

Comment: Cool voicings of E+7♯9  on guitar  `(0)x0113`/`(0)5659x`, `(0)x6533`, and `x(9)89 10 10`

Comment: It's all very well, and may be on topic if the question is re-phrased as to how/why this could be named. BUT - what's the key sig...?

Comment: 'do the work for me' is basically off topic. But also, you didn't show (or explain) the clefs/key signature!

Comment: sorry for my bad english. This is my harmony 1 exercices: write chord symbol and tensions.

Comment: It depends on the function of the chord. All signs point to E7#5#9, but it could also be C9b13(no 7)/E, or even AbMaj7#11/E.

Comment: it´s called E7(#9/b13). You should notice, that the c is a flatted 6, so a natural 5 is possible. At least the way the chord is written. Of course you can see the c as b#, so it depends. E7+(#9) is a good suggestion, too, then. (Out voting thing: Maybe we should take the paragraph out for maintaining musical contexts here. Imagine the chord hand written)